Question on simple fixed-points property
Suppose for a holomorphic function $f(x)$ we have the fixed point equation
$x = f(x) + c,$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.
Is it true, specifically for the values of x that satisfy the original equation (not just any random value of x in the complex plane) that
$f(x) = f( f(x) + c )$ is true too?
All I'm doing is just plugging in the original result into $x,$ so it seems true, but it's so simple I just can't tell if I'm correct or not. I really hope so at least for a class of sufficiently nice functions like polynomials and exponentials and sines and cosines or maybe monotonic functions.

You are just applying $f$ to the same expression, so yes this is true.

You forgot an extra $c$.

@MoisheKohan Nope I did not forget the extra c, that's why I'm asking.
I'm starting with $f(x),$ and then replacing $x$ with the expression I started with, no extra $c$ on the outside.

There's nothing tied to regularity or whatever, if $x = y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ for any function you can apply on said $x$ and $y$.

To be clear for the OP, let y=f(x)+c.
